# UITableView:viewForHeaderInSection, the view can't response

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Now,i have a new problem:

YJHomeViewContoller.m

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [YJHeaderView view];
}
```

YJHeadView.m:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
YJHeaderView *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YJHeaderView" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
}
```

YJHeaderView is my custom view,I use xib to describe.There is a UISWitch in the YJHeaderView.The problem is when i run the application,the UISwitch can't be touched.

Comment: You need to first add an event handler to the button. Please see the docs for `UIButton`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an event handler to the button programmatically like this:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
   btn.tag = section; // Needed to find out which header was tapped
   [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   return btn;
}
```

and of course then define the `btnTapped:` method in the same ViewController like this:

```
-(void)btnTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
   int sectionNo = sender.tag;
   // Do something 
}
```

Comment: You also need to be able to differentiate which section the button belongs to.

Comment: Keep in mind that setting the button's tag to the section number only works if the number and order of the sections is static.